# Java doesnt wait end of timer to repaint

Tags: java, timer

I got trouble to wait with a timer but i don't want to wait the end of the timer to redraw everything, i want when player as the same card to wait 1s draw an hidden card for both then wait 1s but the program should already show it, then drawing the next card. I've tryed timer to stop the program but it doesn't refresh the frame even with .pack() .revalidate() .repaint() . And if i do another thread it doesn't wait at all.

```
ArrayList<Card> bet = Controller.getInstance().playCard();
    for(int i=0;i< bet.size();i++){
        if( (i==0 || i%2==0) ){
            if(i==0||i == (bet.size()-2)){
                playerOne.setPlayedCard(bet.get(i));
            }else {
                signe.setText("=");
                WaitHere();
                playerOne.setPlayedCard(new Carte(-1,backCarte));
                frame.pack();
                WaitHere();
            }
        }else{
            if(i<2||i == bet.size()-1){
                playerTwo.setPlayedCard(bet.get(i));
            }else {
                signe.setText("=");
                playerTwo.setPlayedCard(new Carte(-1,backCarte));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on since the code you've shared doesn't actually contain much relevant code. BUT: you're very likely blocking the event dispatch thread (EDT) and thus repaints might not happen at the time you expect. You probably want a separate thread for your entire game logic and let th main thread (which is the EDT) repaint whenever it needs to.

Comment: yea the problem is i can't put a 'little piece of code' that do how im doing right now.
How would you do that ? I need to wait while doing this piece of code because i don't need to wait if im not in the if. (still begginer with java) Do i need to do the whole thing in another thread ? (i only put the timer last time) @Thomas

Comment: Yes, I would put the entire _game logic_ (or at least the actions triggered by button presses) into a separate thread and update the UI accordingly. However, "still begginer with java" is an indicator you might be in over your head atm and would need to step back a little.

Comment: How can i do that ? Any advice ? It's only my second years of dev im trying to do good practice all i can but google is not enough for everything i do ><

Comment: Thanks it worked ! I needed to do the whole thing in another thread, i didnt know it wouldn't repaint if the thread did not finish @Thomas

Comment: You should read up on the UI concepts in that case :)